# How can I apply a script to every sheet but the first one on a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been working on a shared Google spreadsheet on Google Drive. The document has different sheets with a "Last Modified Date" Cell. I found an script for this to be auto-filled searching here:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
};
```

The script works perfectly, I just changed the column and it worked! The thing is, I need to apply this script to every sheet but the first one. How can I deactivate the use of the script in the first sheet?

Comment: See chat conversation: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/conversation/first-sheet

Comment: I upvoted Vidars answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the active sheet is the first sheet with

```
sheet.getIndex() == 1
```

<sup>([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getIndex%28%29))</sup>

So your function can be

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getIndex() == 1) {
     return; // Don't do anything for first sheet
  }
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this little script, to skip the first sheet

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId() != 0 && e.source.getActiveCell().getColumn() != 2) {
    var row = e.source.getActiveCell().getRow(); 
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    e.source.getRange('B'+row).setValue(time);
  }
}
```

### Example

See example file I created: [little script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFFHU0FZY2l6Q3NoODFNVllpYkNlN3c&usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it, but still stamps the date on the first sheet! :s

Comment: @user62551 Then you're doing something wrong, I works in my sheet.

Comment: I'd might be @Jacob-Jan-Tuinstra but thanks anyway!